# tensor product of two vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be two vector bundles over the same base space $B$. Then $\xi\otimes \eta$ is orientable if and only if $\xi$ and $\eta$ are both orientable. How to prove this true or not true? Thanks.

Is the tensor product of a mobius band with itself orientable ?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the tensor product of a mobius band with itself orientable ?

Comment: yeah... I am confused too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't prove that result it because it is false!
For example the tautological bundle $\xi$ on $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R)$ is non-orientable but its tensor square $\xi^{\otimes 2}=\theta$ is the trivial bundle (like all squares of line bundles on a compact topological space !)  $\theta=\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R) \times \mathbb R$ and is thus certainly orientable.

The assertion that $\xi$ is non orientable can be  proved in an elementary way but I recommend learning to use Stiefel-Whitney classes, which allow you to obtain  such results quite mechanically:
a line bundle $\eta$ on a topological space $M$is orientable iff its first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(\eta)\in H^2(M,\mathbb Z/2)$ is zero and in our case $w_1(\xi)\neq 0\in H^2(M,\mathbb Z/2)$ is the generator of the group  $H^1(\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R),\mathbb Z/2)=\mathbb Z/2$.
The best reference hands-down for Stiefel-Whitney classes (and much, much more)  is Milnor-Stasheff's [Characteristic Classes](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Characteristic_Classes.html?id=5zQ9AFk1i4EC&redir_esc=y) (of which PDF versions float online...).

Answer (score 0):

As Georges points out the result isn't true: $\xi \otimes \eta$ being orientable doesn't imply $\xi$ and $\eta$ orientable. Trivially you can take $\xi$ to be the zero vector bundle...

In the other direction though: A vector bundle $\xi$ (of rank $k$) is orientable iff $\Lambda^k \xi$ is a trivial line bundle iff $\Lambda^k \xi$ has a nowhere vanishing section. Let's assume that both $\xi$ and $\eta$ are orientable.

Let $s \in \Gamma(B, \Lambda^k \xi)$ and $t \in \Gamma(B, \Lambda^l \eta)$ be nowhere vanishing sections. Then you can construct a section $u$ of $\Lambda^{kl} (\xi \otimes \eta)$ by using the following construction on vector spaces:
$$\begin{align}
\Lambda^k V \otimes \Lambda^l W & \to \Lambda^{kl} (V \otimes W) \\
(v_1 \ldots v_k) \otimes (w_1 \ldots w_l) & \mapsto (v_1 \otimes w_1) \ldots (v_1 \otimes w_l) (v_2 \otimes w_1) \ldots (v_k \otimes w_l)
\end{align}$$

This gives a continuous functor on vector spaces, so it yields a functor on vector bundles. And you can check that this is injective for vector spaces (it's tedious). Therefore $u$ is a nowhere vanishing section of $\Lambda^{kl}(\xi \otimes \eta)$, what we wanted.

---

Of course if you're okay with higher level machinery, then $w_1(\xi \otimes \eta)$ can be expressed as a linear polynomial in $w_1(\xi)$ and $w_1(\eta)$ (use the splitting principle and the computation for line bundle $w_1(\ell_1 \otimes \ell_2) = w_1(\ell_1) + w_1(\ell_2)$). So if both are zero (ie $\xi, \eta$ are orientable) then $\xi \otimes \eta$ is orientable.

---

Yet another proof: a vector bundle is orientable if you can find charts and transition functions that preserve orientation, ie. take values in $GL^+_k(\mathbb{R})$. If both $\xi$ and $\eta$ are orientable, you can find such charts, restrict them, and you get charts for $\xi \otimes \eta$ with transition functions expressed in terms of those of $\xi$ and $\eta$. If the transition functions for $\xi$ and $\eta$ have positive determinant, then so do those of $\xi \otimes \eta$ you constructed that way.

Comment: Dear Najib, your hint is incomprehensible to me.  I think you yourself should write a complete  post (not hints!) on the relation between the sections of your three bundles and show how that helps solve the problem.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I suspected the result was only true in one direction but wasn't sure. You can construct a section of $\Lambda^{kl}(\xi \otimes \eta)$ given a section of $\Lambda^k \xi$ and a section of $\Lambda^l \eta$. Of course it doesn't go the other way around... I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Hopefully this is better now.

Comment: Yes, it is correct now .