# let $\xi$ be an arbitrary vector bundle. Is $\xi\otimes\xi$ always orientable?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $\xi=(E,p,B)$ be a line bundle (not nec. orientable). Then the tensor product $\xi\otimes \xi$ is orientable.

I obtain this by choosing $b\in U\cap V$, $U,V$ open in $B$ such that $\phi_U:p^{-1}(U)\longrightarrow U\times \mathbb{K}^n$,$\phi_V:p^{-1}(V)\longrightarrow V\times \mathbb{K}^n$. $(b,x)\in E$. Then $\phi_U(b,x)=(b,u)$, $u\in \mathbb{K}^n$,  $\phi_V(b,x)=(b,v)$, $v\in \mathbb{K}^n$. Then $\phi_V\phi_U^{-1}(b,u)=(b,v)$, $v=\lambda(b)u$. Thus for any $(b,x_1\otimes x_2)\in F_b(\xi_1\otimes \xi_2)$,
$\phi_V\phi_U^{-1}(b,u_1\otimes u_2)=(b,v_1\otimes v_2)=(b,\lambda(b)u_1\otimes\lambda(b)u_2)=(b,\lambda(b)^2 u_1\otimes u_2)$ hence the transition map is a positive scalar multiple and the tensor product is oriented line bundle.

Is my way correct or not? Is there more clear way to prove this?

In general, let $\xi$ be an arbitrary vector bundle. Is $\xi\otimes\xi$ always orientable? How to prove? I am confused. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Ren, your idea is nice but unfortunately it is not true in general that $B$ can be covered by just two open trivializing subsets. And unfortunately your idea does not work with more than two trivializing open subsets.

Comment: You can also see this by observing that determinant of the tensor product of two $n\times n$ real matrices is always positive, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

George's answer is absolutely correct, but here is a more direct argument, which avoids characteristic classes and uses only linear algebra. First of all, each real rank $N$ vector bundle $p:E\to X$ is determined by a cocycle $\xi_{ij}: U_{ij}=U_i\cap U_j\to GL(N, {\mathbb R})$, where $U_k$'s form an open cover of $X$ which trivializes the bundle $p$. (These functions are just the transition maps between different bundle charts.) By definition, the bundle $p$ is orientable if and only if $det(\xi_{ij}(x))>0$ for all $i, j, x\in U_{ij}$. Suppose that we have two vector bundles $E\to X, F\to X$, where $X$ is paracompact; in particular, we can assume that the trivializing covers for both bundles are locally finite. Then, by intersecting their trivializing covers, we can assume that they have a common trivializing cover. It is a straightforward computation to check that if $E, F$ are vector bundles  over $X$ with cocycles $(\alpha_{ij})$ and $(\beta_{ij})$ then the cocycle for their tensor product $E\otimes F$ is
$$
\gamma_{ij}(x)= \alpha_{ij}(x)\otimes \beta_{ij}(x).
$$ 
Here $\otimes$ is the *Kroneker tensor product* of matrices, see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product): Tensor product of matrices represents the tensor product of the corresponding linear maps. Observe furthermore, that if $A$ is an $m\times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix then $det(A\otimes B)=(det(A))^n(det(B))^m$, see the same wikipedia page.

Therefore, if $\alpha_{ij}=\beta_{ij}$ as in OP's question, then the determinant of the tensor product is positive. Hence, $E\otimes E$ is orientable. The same applies to George's remark about tensor product of vector bundles of even rank.

Comment: Very nice, elementary proof: +1

Answer (score 11):

Since I made propaganda for Stiefel-Whitney classes [three hours ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762891/3217), let me show how easy it is to solve your problem with them:

The first Stiefel-Whitney class of the tensor product of two vector bundles $\xi, \eta$ of ranks $r,s$ is $$ w_1(\xi\otimes  \eta)= rw_1(\eta)+s w_1(\xi)  \in H^1(B,\mathbb Z/2 )           $$ and so  in particular $ w_1(\xi\otimes  \xi)= rw_1(\xi)+r w_1(\xi)=0 \in H^1(B,\mathbb Z/2 )            $  [recall that  $H^1(B,\mathbb Z/2 )$ is a $\mathbb Z/2$-vector space].
Since $w_1(\xi\otimes  \xi)=0$, the vector bundle $\xi\otimes  \xi$ is orientable.

**Edit: a bonus**
The displayed formula for the first Stiefel-Whitney class of a tensor product immediately implies by the same reasoning that the tensor product of two vector bundles both of even rank is orientable, **independently of whether the vector bundles themselves are orientable or not !**
Aren't Stiefel- Whitney classes amazing ?

Comment: Yes, they are! But you do not really need them to solve the problem. Simply observe that if $A$ is an $m\times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix then $det(A\otimes B)=(det(A))^n (det(B))^m$. This will do it for both the original problem and the statement about vector bundles of even rank.

Comment: Dear @  studiosus, I would encourage you to promote your interesting comment into a complete answer.

Comment: Dear George: OK, I just did.

Answer (score 0):

If the base space is paracompact, you can always pull back the vector bundle over another space such that the pull back bundle splits. Then the statement holds by functoriality of Stiefel Whitney classes and injectivity of the map. For general base space case, I think the proof might be a bit involved, and I do not have a proof at the moment.

Comment: You can't canonically pull back the vector bundle to the classifying space: it's the other way round.  Anyway that wouldn't help:  pull-backs of a bundle say absolutely nothing about the orientability or trivality of the original bundle, as shown by pulling back any bundle to a point!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Under the assumption of paracompactness, you can do that. Mind that in this case the pulling back map is injective.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: You are right the arrow is wrong; corrected.

Comment: Dear Bombyx mori , the arrow is now  in the correct  direction **but** the bundle on the classifying space does not split as a direct sum of line bundles. If it did, then  its pull back, which is the original bundle, would  split too, which it has no reason to do !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I see. Perhaps I should revise again as my knowledge of splitting principle is quite shaky.

Comment: Dear Bombyx, I think the problem is in the confusion between the splitting principle based on   maps **going into $B$** and the classifying space whose maps **come from $B$** .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Yes, I think I was confused on that. Thanks for pointing out.