# Elementary and purely topological proof of the non-triviality of tautological complex line bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, projective-space

I need some hints about the proof of the non triviality of the tautological complex line bundle, in a pure topological manner.

Let $E$ be the t.c.l. bundle defined in this way $$ E= \{ (x,v) \in \mathbb{P}\mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \mid  v \in x \}$$ with the obvious projection map $\pi: E \to\mathbb{P}\mathbb{C}^n$, $ (x,v) \mapsto x$

Looking around, (Milnor-Stasheff's book "Characteristic Classes" page 152 prob. 13-E) the hint to prove the non-triviality of $E$ is to define an holomorphic section and then prove that must be constant and so the zero section (Liouville Theorem I think, but I admit I didn't spend too much time over this hint)

> I'm my work, I didn't introduce any kind of differential structure over $E$ ($E$ is a topological space with the projection, the complex vector space-fibers and local triviality property) so, according to me, I'm not allowed to speak about holomorphic function and so I need another approach to prove the statement. I saw that in the real case a kind of approach is to use the Intermediate Value Theorem (to prove that there can't be a non-vanishing continuous section), but here in the complex case it's not valid.

In conclusion I don't have any ideas on how to deal with this proof with my work hypothesis.

**ADDENDUM:** There is a very short answer using Chern Classes as shown by Georges Elencwajg (thanks for the answer!). This kind of tool is very advanced and I feel like there must be some more elementary tricks to exploit. The original hint was to use [Liouville's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), but I've modified the text deleting all references to the differential structure over $\mathbb{PC}^n$

Comment: One elementary idea that comes to mind is that you only need to prove this for $n=1$, and it will automatically follow for all $n \geq 1$. (Because if you have a nonzero section in $E_n$, then you can restrict it to $\mathbb{PC}^1$ and get a nonzero section in $E_1$). So you have to think about just one fixed bundle instead of a whole family of them.

Comment: Another idea is that if you have a global nonzero section in $E_1$, you can divide it by the norm at each point, and this will give you a global section in $E' = \{(x, v) \in \mathbb{PC}^1 \times S^3 \mid v \in x\}$, where $S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ consists of all elements with unit norm. But $E'$ is simply the [Hopf fibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) $S^3 \to S^2$. So what remains to show is that the Hopf fibration doesn't have a global section, which isn't hard.

Comment: Nice comments @Dan:+1.  I have written an elementary answer in that spirit, since Riccardo seems to find characteristic classes too sophisticated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an elementary answer,  using only the second homology group $H_2(-,\mathbb Z)$

As Dan Shved noticed in a comment, we may reduce to the case $n=1$.
Assume for contradiction that we have a never zero section $\sigma$ of  $\pi:E\to \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$ .
Let $p:S^3 \to \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$ be the restriction of $\pi$ to the sphere $S^3\subset \mathbb C^2$ formed by the vectors $x\in \mathbb C^2$ of norm ||x||=1.
By dividing the hypothetical  section $\sigma $ of $\pi$ by the norm we obtain a section $s:\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C \to S^3: x\mapsto s(x)=\frac {\sigma(x)}{||\sigma(x)||}$ of $p$.
But then the  composition $$p\circ s=Id_{\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C}: \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C \to S^3 \to \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$$ yields in homology the composition $$Id_{H_2( \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C ,\mathbb Z)}:H_2( \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z\to H_2( S^3,\mathbb Z)=0\to H_2( \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$$ a clear absurdity.
This contradiction shows that the section $\sigma$ cannot exist and that the tautological bundle is thus not topologically trivial.

**Edit**
As an answer to Riccardo's comment let me clarify the following.
There is a slight abuse of language above:  we have an embedding of the sphere $j:S^3\hookrightarrow E$ in  which the pair $(v,w)$ with $||v||^2+||w||^2=1$ is sent to $j(v,w)=([v:w],(v,w))\in E$.
In my answer, when I write $S^3$ I actually mean its homeomorphic image $j(S^3)\subset E$.

Comment: thanks for your effort, now I need some times to understand your answer and eventually accept it ! Thanks again

Comment: Nice answer. If I was forced to provide a proof that Hopf's fibration isn't trivial, I would probably end up comparing $H_2(-,\mathbb{Z})$ of $S^3$ and $S^2 \times S^1$ too.

Comment: You are welcome, Riccardo!

Comment: Dear @Dan, yes I'm sure you could have given an equivalent (or better) answer. I took the liberty of posting a detailed answer because I feared that your excellent comments might be too crisp for a complete beginner (I don't allude to Riccardo, whose familiarity with topology I don't know)

Comment: I was reluctant to post a complete answer. My topology's a bit rusty due to the rare use, and I could have easily overcomplicated things if asked for details. So thanks for posting :)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I understand the general spirit of the answer, but there are some kind of details that I didn't understand very well:

$1)$ how can you restrict $\pi$ to $S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$? are you restricting $\pi$ to $ \{x\} \times S^3$ for some $x \in \mathbb{PC}^1$?

$2)$ the section $s$ goes from $\mathbb{PC}^1 \to \mathbb{PC}^1 \times S^3$ (not the trivial bundle clearly, but the codomain has this form according to me) ? Anyway, $s = (x,f(x))$ for some $f : \mathbb{PC}^1 \to S^3$ and so we can treat the $s$ as the $f$.

Comment: (continue here) and the reasoning can be carried over in the same way. The last doubt is: the absurd is that I construct the functor given by the identity which is trivial (thanks to the trivial group in the middle of the sequence)?


My observations are to be intended as "Have I understand correctly your reasoning?" I don't want to "do the teacher" obviously. I only need some feedback over my understanding of your proof and how to formalize it properly. Thanks again for your answer and comments

Comment: Dear Ricardo: yes, the absurdity is that a composition of two morphisms $\mathbb Z\to 0\to \mathbb Z$ (where the middle group is the zero group) is the zero morphism and thus cannot be the identity of $\mathbb Z$.  I have written an edit clarifying (I hope) the role of the $3$-sphere $S^3$.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear, I didn't know such embedding, well thanks for this very enlightening answer. (accepted of course)

Comment: It is my pleasure, Riccardo.

Answer (score 4):

There is an elementary proof which mirrors the proof of the corresponding real statement given in Milnor & Stasheff (Theorem $2.1$).

Let $p : S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ be the quotient map and $\sigma : \mathbb{CP}^n \to E$ be a continuous section of $E$. Then $\sigma\circ p : S^{2n+1} \to E$ is given by $(\sigma\circ p)(v) = ([v], s(v))$ where $s : S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is such that $s(v) \in [v]$. So $s(v) = t(v)v$ for some continuous map $t : S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Note that

$$(\sigma\circ p)(-v) = \sigma(p(-v)) = \sigma([-v]) = ([-v], s(-v)) = ([-v], t(-v)(-v)) = ([v], -t(-v)v)$$

but

$$(\sigma\circ p)(-v) = \sigma(p(-v)) = \sigma([-v]) = \sigma([v]) = ([v], t(v)v)$$

so $t(v) = -t(-v)$. By the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem (applied to $t|_{S^2}$), there is $v_0 \in S^{2n+1}$ such that $t(-v_0) = t(v_0)$. Therefore, $t(v_0) = -t(-v_0) = -t(v_0)$, so $t(v_0) = 0$ and hence

$$\sigma([v_0]) = ([v_0], t(v_0)v_0) = ([v_0], 0) = 0 \in E_{[v_0]}.$$

As $E$ does not admit a nowhere-zero section, $E$ is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Use first Chern class $c_1$, a purely topological invariant ( [Milnor-Stasheff](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/1571.html), Theorem 14.4, page 160):
$$c_1(E)=-1\neq c_1(\mathbb P^n_\mathbb C\times\mathbb C)=0\in H^2(\mathbb P^n_\mathbb C,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$$

Comment: More propaganda for characteristic classes [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/762891/3217) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/763138/3217)

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I've read about Chern Classes, but I need some more elementary method (if possible): For real tautological line bundle the intermediate value theorem is the way, but in the complex case without a differential structure I don't know what to use. Even if your method is purely topologic, I need some more elementary disquisition, as I already said, if possible.

Comment: Anyway, the up vote is well deserved, because the answer is correct, but I need elementary reasonings